# Jasmine Angular unit-test wait for spyOn component promise to be resolved

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

We unit-test an Angular component that has the purpose to select and upload files.
In the component we convert files to base64 strings (backend requirement)
and do some other checks.

Only after the files have been converted to base64, the template updates and shows
to-be uploaded attachments.

This is what we want to unit-test: the visibility of a list of base64 encoded files to be uploaded.

Here is a link to our MWE (for brevity we removed specific logic that is not relevant to our question): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-promise-await-bjvxuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Is there a way to make jasmine wait for our Angular components returned promise to have resolved, such that we deterministically know that the template will have re-rendered, so that we can expect the attachment list to have been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `Angular` solutions and most likely not `jasmine` solutions.

There are many ways to wait for promises in Angular:

1.) `async` and `await fixture.whenStable()`

```
it('should do xyz', async () => {
  // do some stuff that creates promises and puts them in queue

  // wait for pending promises to complete before continuing
  await fixture.whenStable();

  // promises completed, continue with assertions or other stuff
});
```

2.) `waitForAsync` and `fixture.whenStable()`

`waitForAsync` helper method waits for promises created to be resolved before completing the test

```
it('should do xyz', waitForAsync(() => {
  // do some stuff that creates promises and puts them in queue

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // do your assertions here when the promises complete
  });
}));
```

3.) `fakeAsync` and `tick()`

```
it('should do xyz', fakeAsync(() => {
  // do some stuff that creates promises and puts them in queue

  // wait for promises to resolve before continuing
  tick();

  // do assertions or other stuff
}));
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-testing-async-fakeasync

The above is a good article. You can continue learning about `fakeAsync` and `tick`, `fixture.whenStable()` and `waitForAsync`.

==== Edit =====

```
it('shows attachments in attachmentslist', fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    // in our test we actually construct and use a mockFileDataTransfer object here
    // and trigger a dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change'));
    // to better mimic user interaction, we left all of this out for brevity

    // act
    // this is not in our own test, but for demonstration purposes we directly call
    // the method here.
    component.onFilesDropped();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // add tick() to make the pending promises complete
     tick();
    // add tick(#) to make the timer proceed in a fake way that duration
     tick(250);
    
    // the rest

}));
```

Comment: Thanks @AliF50 for your elaborate reply. However, none of these options will provide a solution: fakeAsync won't work in this case, because the component really does do async work (converting binary to base64, also in the unit-test: we do not want to mock this as we want include it in the unit-test)

async is superseded by waitForAsync in our Angular version and unfortunately does not solve our problem either: the promise is created and awaited in the component, this is not something that happens in our test.

Comment: There is the `JavaScript` async and there is the Angular `waitForAsync`. `waitForAsync` was once called `async` but Angular changed it to `waitForAsync` to get rid of the confusion. Check out my edit, something like that should work. Also, if you can make a `StackBlitz` with the unit tests running instead of the UI, I could help more then. I am not sure how to do this though.

Comment: We could not get it to work, so in the end what we did was abstract the base64 code into it's own service (this is a good pattern anyhow) and test it separately, and mock the base64 conversion Promise in our component test by returning Promise.resolve('mockBase64String'). This causes there to be no need to actually wait for the component to do async stuff and removes all of this complexity.
I don't believe fakeAsync would have worked, because it fakes the passing of time and just like an XHR request, base64 is actually async and requires real time to complete :(

Comment: Awesome, that sounds like a better pattern. `tick()` with no argument waits for promises in queue to complete (at least it should) and `tick(3000)` would pass the time by 3 seconds so it depends on how you use it (with argument or not argument.